# How to remove an object from priority queue of user defined type

Tags: java, dictionary, queue, heap, priority-queue

i have my priority queue defined as

```
PriorityQueue< LRUCache > qu = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comp() );
```

here LRUCache class has the variable key and freq based on which i created the Comparator.
if i have to remove a particular object from priority queue based on certain key and freq 
how can i do that

```
qu.remove(new LRUCache(key , freq ) ) // like this or something better ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can but first, the `equals()` method in your `LRUCache` class because the `PriorityQueue` uses it internally for finding the object to remove it.

i.e this is the `indexOf(...)` code from the `PriorityQueue` which called be `remove(...)` method

```
    private int indexOf(Object o) {
        if (o != null) {
            final Object[] es = queue;
            for (int i = 0, n = size; i < n; i++)
                if (o.equals(es[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

, Just add to your `LRUCache` class the `equals()`

**The `equals(...)` method will check the following:**

1- Check if the obj parameter equals the current object with **this** keyword then return **true**

2- Check if the obj parameter equals null or not the same class **"invalid state"** then return **false**

3- Otherwise the obj parameter will be valid and the same type, so cast to the target class which is here `LRUCache`, and check with whatever properties in the class based on your needs, here they are `key` and `freq`

```
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
                return false;
            LRUCache cache = (LRUCache) obj;
            return key.equals(cache.key) && freq == cache.freq;
        }
```

Comment: can you explain the override equals() part please?

Comment: @Sophie I have updated the answer with more details, you can check it. If there is a need for more details please put a comment